# insert node in BST

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I know how to insert node in Binary Search Tree but in the code below Actual Node does not contain pointer to next node.

Can some one please give me hint how to navigate left or right of Node in insert_item function?
Can someone please bail me out.

```
 typedef struct Link
{
    struct link *left;
    struct link *right;
} Link;

 typedef struct Node
{
    struct Link link;
    unsigned char c;
} Node;

Link* create_link()
{
    Link* first_link;
    first_link = malloc( sizeof( Link ) );   
    return( first_link );
}

Node* create_node( unsigned char val  )
 {
    Node* temp = malloc( sizeof( temp ) );
          temp->link.left = create_link();
          temp->link.right = create_link();
          temp->c       = val;
     return( temp );
 }
Link* insert_link( Link *link, key )
{

}

void insert_item( Node* root, unsigned char key, L )
{
    if( !root )
    {
        root = create_node( key );
    }
    /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
    else
   {
        if( key < root->c )
        {
            insert_item( root->link ); // The node  does not have pointer ?? how would I traverse left or right?
        }
   }
}

int main()
{
    Node* root = NULL;
    root = create_node( 60 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `struct link *left; struct link *right;` : `link` typo as `Link`

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "next" node in the context of a BST?

Comment: `Node* create_node( unsigned char val ='0' )`? C this ain't. Also, in that function you should really `malloc()` memory for `temp`.

Comment: `temp->link.left = create_link();...temp->link.left = NULL;` <- memory leak.

Comment: Since you tagged your question as "C++" get rid of the `typedef struct` syntax.  It's not needed in C++ because every structure is a type.  If you're programming in C, leave them in.  Either way, please adjust your tags so we know which language you are programming in and so that we can respond with language appropriate answers.

Comment: Have you reviewed the plethora of Linked List questions already on StackOverflow?  There are examples in both C and C++.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: He asked almost the same question about an hour ago. Apparently deleted and re-asked.

Comment: The code you posted is working fine, can't figure out your problem

Comment: Is that for C or C++ actually? These are different languages.

Comment: `void insert_item( Node* root, unsigned char key, L )` ??

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: according to his usage of `malloc()` it has to be C actually.

Comment: @Olaf:  The `malloc` function, alone, does not determine if the program is C or C++.  The `malloc` function is valid in both languages.  One difference is the casting of the result from `malloc`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: "according to his usage of ..." That's why I wrote is as I did. Also: who would implement a BST that way in C++? Anyway, let him rollback if he thinks different.

Comment: Thanks Everyone  . But I am looking for hint to insert into function. If you can give me some hint , that will be great.  And also it is completely C based

Answer (score 0):

This is screwed up to say the least:

```
Node* create_node( unsigned char val  )
 {
    Node* temp = malloc( sizeof( temp ) );
          temp->link.left = create_link();
          temp->link.right = create_link();
          temp->c       = val;
     return( temp );
 }
```

You are allocating room for a pointer, `sizeof(temp)`, since `temp` is a pointer.

You should allocate memory for the structure:

```
[C++] Node * temp = new Node;
[C]   Node * temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

You should assign pointers to 0 or some kind of *leaf* value if they don't point to anything:

```
[C++] struct Link
{
  Link() : left(0), right(0)
  { }
  Link * left;
  Link * right;
};
[C] temp->link.right = 0; temp->link.left = 0;
```

In a binary tree, you can place new nodes as a right or left child of a parent.  The determination *depends on the kind or purpose* of your tree.

*Note:  In C++ you should be using a smart pointer for the links.*

Comment: Thanks  . But I am looking for hint to insert into function. If you can give me some hint , that will be great.

Answer (score -2):

You are setting the left and right pointers to NULL after creating them. Get rid of the following code, and you should be good to go.

temp->link.left = NULL;
temp->link.right = NULL;